# Checking The Value Of A JSON File With A Discord Bot Command

Tags: python, json, discord, discord.py, bots

Okay, so I want to start off by saying I know that JSON is not a database and it shouldn't be used as one, but, all I want to do is get some information from the file itself, so while it may not be good practice, and I probably won't use JSON as a database, I just want to see what can be possible with this file format.  Anyways, sorry for the side tangent.  What I want to do is be able to have a discord bot command that lets you view the level you are; as I'm making a Discord Leveling Bot for some Discord Servers, this level is stored in the discord bot along with a users ID and amount of Experience they have so far.  Here is some code I tried to use, but it didn't seem to work once so ever.  So, any pointers on it would be useful, as well as just some general help as how to possibly make this a more usable discord bot in general as I have only made a few discord bots in total.

Snippet of the code where I attempted to make a level command:

```
#The Function For Checking Your Current Level.
@client.command(name="level")
async def get_level(ctx, users, user, channel):
  with open("users.json") as f:   
    json_information = json.load(f)
    level_information = json_information.get(str(user.id))
  await ctx.channel.send(f"{user.mention} Is Level {level_information.get('level')}.")
```

The Whole Script:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from time import time
import json
import discord
import os
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!")

#On Ready Event.
@client.listen()
async def on_ready():
  print("Bot Ready.")
  #time.sleep(1)
  print("Logged In As:  {0.user}".format(client))

#Function For Getting A Users Information And Level Them Up.
@client.listen()
async def on_member_join(member):
  with open("users.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)

  await update_data(users, member)

  with open("users.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)

#Member's Messages.
member_messages = {}

#Function For The System That Creates And Uses The Leveling System.
@client.listen()
async def on_message(message):
  global member_messages

  if message.author.id not in member_messages:
    member_messages[message.author.id] = 0

  current_time = time()
  last_message_requirement = current_time - 2
  
  if member_messages[message.author.id] <= last_message_requirement:
    with open("users.json", "r") as f:
      users = json.load(f)
  
    await update_data(users, message.author)
    await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
    await level_up(users, message.author, message.channel)
  
    with open("users.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(users, f)

      member_messages[message.author.id] = current_time

#The Function For Updating The Leveling Data.
async def update_data(users, user):
  if not str(user.id) in users:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["experience"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["level"] = 1

#The Function For Adding Experience To Someone's Level.
async def add_experience(users, user, exprience):
  users[str(user.id)]["experience"] += exprience

#The Function For Leveling People Up.
async def level_up(users, user, channel):
  experience = users[str(user.id)]["experience"]
  level_start = users[str(user.id)]["level"]
  level_end = int(experience ** (1/4))

  if level_start < level_end:
    await channel.send(f"{user.mention} Has Leveled Up!  They Have Leveled Up To Level {level_end}!")
    users[str(user.id)]["level"] = level_end

#The Function For Checking Your Current Level.
@client.command(name="level")
async def get_level(ctx, users, user, channel):
  with open("users.json") as f:   
    json_information = json.load(f)
    level_information = json_information.get(str(user.id))
  await ctx.channel.send(f"{user.mention} Is Level {level_information.get('level')}.")

client.run(os.getenv("Token"))
client.run(os.environ["Token"])
```

Comment: Describe "it didn't work"? What errors do you get? What weird behaviour do you see?

Comment: This is the error I was getting when trying out the command:  https://pastebin.com/hKhwVu8U

Comment: Looking at the error, `users` is required but not given. When running the command, you need to make sure to provide all arguments. If `users` isn't required for the command to work, simply change it to `users=None`; this way, it becomes an optional argument and not a required argument.

Comment: I tried ```@client.command(name="level", users=None)```  but I got this error:  https://pastebin.com/duQuhjzn

Answer (score 0):

Noticed some issues in your code

1. What is the point of `experience ** (1/4)` construction? It is basically raising the experience to the ¼ power. What for?
2. `users` argument is never used in your command. Why even add it? Same for `channel`.
3. `user` arg is not typehinted properly which means you are attempting to access inexistent attributes of `str` in your code.

You are correct about not using json as a database. If you wanna see "what is possible with that file format" I can tell you — settings/config data or transmitting data over network. Do not use it for data storage.